# Wireshark not playing g729 codec

Tags: wireshark

Good day All.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS  with Wireshark Version 3.0.7

I am having issues playing my g729 audio from the RTP player.

Please note that the same pcaps play 100% in Windows.

```bsh
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu bionic main

$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details, nor where you got the package from as it's not a Ubuntu sourced package

Comment: Please see edited post.